# Continuity of the greatest integer function

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let F be a function defined as $F:[-0.5,2] \rightarrow R$ such that:

$$ f(x)=[x²-3]$$

Find the number of points where F is not continuous in $[-0.5,2]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the function part wise where it breaks or becomes integral in this case.

$$f(x) = \left\{-3 ; -\frac{1}{2}<x<1 \\
-2;1<x<\sqrt2 \\
-1; \sqrt2<x<\sqrt3 \\
0;\sqrt3<x<2 \right\}$$

So clearly the function is not continuous at $x=1,\sqrt2,\sqrt3,2$

So its 4 points.

BTW my school teacher told me this trick : $[continuous \ and \ differentiable \ function]$ is discontinuous at points where it becomes integer, but not a point of minima.

So here It was evident from graph of $y=x^2-3$ that all points where function becomes integral except $x=0$ are points of discontinuity......:-) 
Hope it helps....Stay Home,Stay safe

Comment: Correction: I forgot to write why x=2 is also included in list while listing part wise definiton.......F(2)=1

Comment: This helps a ton!! Also will [x³] be discontinuous at 0? Since 0 is not a point of minima.

Comment: @user762391 of course not try writing it in similar fashion of part wise function and check for yourself........You can also impart a graphical method to check this for functions